# CS0029: Cannot Implicty convert "char" to "bool"

Tags: c#

I've used this code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace The_Browser
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.GoForward();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.GoBack();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.hu/?gws_rd=ssl#q=" + textBox2.Text);
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate("google.hu");
    }

    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar = (Char)ConsoleKey.Enter) ;
    }
}

}
```

And not work. What the problem? :?

Comment: This looks like C# not like C++

Comment: Even in C#, what on earth is `if (e.KeyChar = (Char)ConsoleKey.Enter) ;` supposed to do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `textBox1_KeyPress` event handler, you are actually using assignment operator i.e. `=` instead of comparison one i.e. `==`.

Use

```
if (e.KeyChar == (Char)ConsoleKey.Enter)
```

instead of

```
if (e.KeyChar = (Char)ConsoleKey.Enter)
```